# How to create sql selection based on condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following database which shows characteristics of attributes as follows:

```
attributeId | attributeCode | groupCode
------------+---------------+-----------
1           | 10            | 50
1           | 10            | 50
1           | 12            | 50
```

My desired result from a select would be:

```
attributeId | groupcount | code10 | code12
------------+------------+--------+--------
1           | 1          | 2      | 1
```

Which means: `attributeId = 1` has only one `groupCode` (50), where `attributeCode=10` occurs 2 times and `attributeCode=12` occurs 1 time.

Of course the following is not valid, but you get the idea of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
select attributeId,
       count(distinct(groupCode)) as groupcount,
       attributeCode = 10 as code10, 
       attributeCode = 12 as code12
from table
group by attributeId;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT attributeId, COUNT(DISTINCT groupCode) AS groupcount,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN attributeCode = 10 THEN 1 END) AS code10,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN attributeCode = 12 THEN 1 END) AS code12
FROM mytable
GROUP BY attributeId
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47cf0/1)

Comment: That's interesting. Do you think it matters if I use `COUNT` or `SUM(..)` (both work and produce the same results)?

Comment: @membersound It should return the same result. I personally find `COUNT`  more suitable because it expresses what you really want to do in this case: count the number of either `10` or `12` value occurrences.